# Debugging a failed ant build

Tags: android, linux, ant

I'm trying to compile and release an android app via headless linux server using ant. I'm getting the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1
```

This is line 698:

```
proguardFile="${out.absolute.dir}/proguard.txt">
```

How can I find out what this ${out.absolute.dir} is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the -d (debug) and -v (verbose) flags to your ant command.  You'll get a lot of extra output, but it should give you a clue.